# E-mail settings for Microsoft Exchange on Windows 7

Tags: email

I have outlook already and have Microsoft Exchange (on my laptop) installed, but the settings aren't correct.  I assumed they were the same; however, everytime I try to e-mail an article it says that I am "offline".  I went to change the settings, but it says this, "Log onto incoming mail server (POP3): Outlook cannot connect to your incoming (POP3) e-mail server. If you continue to receive this message, contact your server administrator or Internet service provider (ISP). Send test e-mail message: Cannot find the e-mail server. Verify the server information in your account properties."

What are the correct e-mail settings from Microsoft Exchange or can I use my outlook.com e-mail as my default on my laptop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Microsoft Exchange is a server product. Are you sure what you have installed on your laptop is Microsoft Exchange? Perhaps you mean Outlook or Windows Live Mail? Can you clarify by editing your question please.

Comment: Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 actually. Oops! Then why does a window always pop up saying "Cannot configure Microsoft Exchange?" or server offline? I have never been on this website before - terribly impressed with how quickly you got back to me thank you so much!

Comment: I've converted this to a comment for you. You may want to use the 'contact us' button and request the account this was posted as, and the account you have here are merged